# Display ExpandableList Child without Touching Header

Tags: java, android, click

The default behavior of ExpandableListView is to collapse a group when its header is clicked. Is it possible to display it without clicking? Always show the children without clicking

Comment: do you want to show all group's childs by default or just a single child.?

Comment: All groups Childs by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code

```
ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exListview);
int count = viewAdapter.getGroupCount();
for (int position = 1; i <= count; position++)
{
    mExpandableListView.expandGroup(position - 1);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried like this ?? 
ExpandableListView lst;
lst.expandGroup(0);
lst.expandGroup(1);